# F# Computation Expression - Type woes

Tags: f#, monads, computation-expression

I'm fighting with a few pathetic lines of code but cannot wrap my head around the problem - for whatever reason I can't get under the principle of this aspect of F#'s type system and so far all my reading hasn't worked.

Can anyone point out to me the rather stupid schoolboy error I'm making here? I know I am making one, I just cannot see it! I'm trying to climb out of painful beginner land on this, so grokking the full principle of why this doesn't work is my aim - any help would be gratefully received!

It's a simple exercise - just a practice one actually that doesn't really need a monad to perform, however I really want these things under my belt for my next project.

```
let stringToInt str = Int32.TryParse(str)

type wk() =
    member this.Bind(f , str) = f str
    member this.Return(f ) = f 

let strInt = new wk()

let test a   =  strInt{let! b  = strInt.Bind a stringToInt 
                   return b}


let x = test  "10"  
printfn "%s" x
```

I'm getting the following:

```
Program.fs(117,14): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
(string -> bool * int) -> ('a -> 'a) -> 'b    
but here has type  string
```

Update: Based on help from below, I have this working now:

```
 open System
 open System.Threading

 let stringToInt str = snd <| Int32.TryParse(str)   


 type wk() =
   member this.Bind(funct, str) =  funct str  
   member this.Return(str) = str

   let strInt = new wk()
   //Jack P syntax!
   let test2 str funct = strInt{
                         let! b = funct str
                         return b
                               }
   let go2 = test2 ("10", stringToInt) |>  printfn "%A"
```

Though working is perhaps still not conceptually there yet - getting the value to print doesn't happen. I'll keep hacking through - I've done tons of reading, that's where I got the exercise from but the only way I'll get the concept is to continue to fight with it I think.

I succeeded in a simpler form on my blog: http://richardgriffiths.azurewebsites.net/?p=2332
so I just need to bust the syntax/concept barrier I've got with the type system.

Comment: I'm seriously not sure what you're trying to do here. For a gentle introduction to computation expressions, maybe try to build one for `Option` type, it's simple enough and you should get the grasp of the basics...

Comment: It's just an exercise - simply return the integer value of a string, if indeed if In32.TryParse(str) has an integer in it. I'm basically learning the computation expression idea, I've succeeded in an earlier example.

Comment: I have almost never needed to create my own computation expressions. Monads in F# are not needed like they are in Haskell. If you really feel you need to understand them, though, here's a start: http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/series/computation-expressions.html

Comment: @Grundoon thank you, that's one of my main sources right now. I've a project in mind that needs parallel computation - I don't want to be conceptually handicapped when thinking through how to achieve it :)

Comment: In your updated code, you need to change the `go2` binding to: `let go2 = test2 "10" stringToInt |>  printfn "%A"`. `test2` is defined in curried form (because you haven't wrapped the entire argument list in parentheses) so you need to call it accordingly.

Comment: @JackP. the compiler don't love me for that unfortunately. The type '('a -> 'a) -> 'b' does not match the type 'int' - I'll have to hack through this the hard way tonight :) Have a merry Xmas!!

Answer (score 4):

The whole point of computation expressions in F# is that you don't have to explicitly call the `Bind`, `Return`, etc. methods on your builder instance (`strInt` in your case). That's the difference between `let` and `let!` -- in a computation expression, `let!` bindings are compiled so they call the `Bind` method of the builder instance. So you'd write your code like this:

```
let test a =
    strInt {
    let! b  = stringToInt a
    return b
    }
```

However -- the code above still doesn't work because your `Bind` and `Return` methods aren't defined correctly (they're not monadic). I second Patryk's suggestion (in his comment) -- you should spend some time practicing with the simple, common monads (e.g., `option`) before you start trying to write your own. It's easy to *use* F# computation expressions, but defining your own computation expressions is an intermediate/advanced-level topic.

Comment: P - I've yet to make this syntax work for me. What I'm in part fighting is my own syntax blindness here as the compiler, of course, is far more exacting than what I started with (VB). I did a simpler exercise no trouble, this is the gate I need to bust next :)

Comment: P - I was a bit premature, made your syntax work now :). Now just for the side effects (actually evaluate and print the result!)

Answer (score 3):

You've defined `Bind` to take a tupled argument (which is correct for a computation builder), but you're passing the arguments in curried form (`strInt.Bind a stringToInt` instead of `strInt.Bind(a, stringToInt)`).